# AngularJS1.2 & Angular using Microfrontend

Tags: angularjs, angular

I am working in a project which is developed using AngularJS1.2, since it is older I am thinking to write feature modules in separate app using Angular and then with the help of Microfrontend thinking to combine with older app. To achieve this, I am not able to get a good source/guide. Can anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I see 3 ways but haven't tried any of them though. So, I don't have any working solution.

1. Have a route from angularjs that points to angular app(full page load) and everything from there onwards, angular handles everything. There is no angularjs involved. This may not be the best option.
2. Let angular code load on demand when the feature is required and provide placeholders for the angular features inside angularjs project. This way you can share custom scope to nested child angular project.
3. Use web components developed in angular(angular elements) and use them in your angularjs application. They work independent of technology/framework/library.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.